# OutOfMemory exception for a table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, out-of-memory

I am trying to fill table with random color in each column(a rough idea to create an image in table form)(I may sound somewhat funny).
I have created one view with code given below but is giving me OutOfMemoryException. Any kind of help will be appreciable.
I am doing it in an MVC application.

```
<table>
@(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    red = random.Next(0, 255);
    green = random.Next(0, 255);
    blue = random.Next(0, 255);
    hexColour = String.Format("#{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", red, green, blue);
    <tr style="height:1px !important; width:1px !important;background-color:'@hexColour'">
    @{
    for(int j=0;i<10;j++)
    {
        red = random.Next(0, 255);
        green = random.Next(0, 255);
        blue = random.Next(0, 255);
        hexColour = String.Format("#{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", red, green, blue);
        <td style="height:1px !important; width:1px !important;background-color:'@hexColour'"></td>
    }
    </tr>
    }
}
</table>
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(int j=0;i<10;j++)
```

should be:

```
for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
```

Comment: Ohh man, I shoud have noticed that.
anyway thank you very much. :)